# How to change the languages of the next activities by a spinner in the main activity?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in using Android studio, And this is my first project.

I am using a spinner with 5 languages in the main activity the language is changing in the first activity only but the next activities are not changed when I click on the button to switch me to the next pages still as the default language en, I want the code to continue my project?

Also I made the languages strings and the values folders also local helper class.

I want the code which help me to continue translating the next activities.

Layout code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:background="@drawable/language_background"     tools:context="com.example.dell.egyptholidayapp.Activities.LanguageActivity">      <TextView         android:id="@+id/language_title"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"         android:layout_marginTop="11dp"         android:text="SELECT YOUR LANGUAGE"         android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"         android:textSize="20dp"         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView         android:id="@+id/logo_image"         android:layout_width="120sp"         android:layout_height="120sp"         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"         android:layout_marginTop="43dp"         android:adjustViewBounds="false"         android:contentDescription=""         android:src="@mipmap/app_icon2"         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/language_title" />      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView         android:id="@+id/selecting_language"         android:layout_width="300dp"         android:layout_height="40dp"         android:layout_below="@+id/logo_image"         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"         android:layout_marginTop="92dp"         app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"         app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"         app:cardElevation="10dp"         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo_image">          <RelativeLayout             android:layout_width="match_parent"             android:layout_height="match_parent">              <Spinner                 android:id="@+id/spinner"                 android:layout_width="284dp"                 android:layout_height="25dp"                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"                 tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"                 tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />         </RelativeLayout>      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>      <Button         android:id="@+id/next_button"         android:layout_width="140dp"         android:layout_height="40dp"         android:layout_below="@+id/selecting_language"         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"         android:background="@color/colorBlue2"         android:text="NEXT"         android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"         android:textSize="15dp"         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selecting_language" /> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

java code

```
import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Intent; import android.graphics.Typeface; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.View; import android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.Spinner; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;  import com.example.dell.egyptholidayapp.R;  import java.lang.reflect.Field;  public class LanguageActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {      private TextView myLanguageTittle;     private Button myNextButton;      @Override     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);          Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);         try{             Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");             popup.setAccessible(true);             android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow)popup.get(spinner);             popupWindow.setHeight(500);         }         catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e){         }         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.language_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);         spinner.setAdapter(adapter);         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);          Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf");         myLanguageTittle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.language_title);         myNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);         myLanguageTittle.setTypeface(myTypeface);         myNextButton.setTypeface(myTypeface);          myNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             @Override             public void onClick(View v) {                 Intent i = new Intent(LanguageActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);                 startActivity(i);             }         });     }      @Override     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {         String sSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();         Toast.makeText(this, sSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      }      @Override     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {      }      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);         return true;     }  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you change the language of the First activity. You already programmed it to change while your other activity is unaware of the fact that you change the language in the first activity.

The Answer would be
Use

**Shared preference**

So whenever you change language store that in your shared preference so that when you go to the next activity you can get the common shared preference and change the language accordingly.

Comment: No I can't. I only guide you through. But in the end you have to code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the frequent API changes, Changing the language at runtime is pretty messy. Fortunately there is a very good guide on how to do this on all Android API levels. 
Give it a try https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758